# Issue Creating Own LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created my own LinkedList, and am running into a type issue with one of my methods.
I keep receiving the error:

```
Error: /Users/randymartinuzzi/Documents/EECS 233/FBLinkedList.java:100: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: FBLinkedList.Node
```

Any Time my Program runs the line:
`Node n = iterator().next();` or `n = iterator().next();`

I am not sure why this is because my method `next()` returns a Node.

I have attached my full code below. Any suggestions on what the issue may be would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FBLinkedList implements Iterable, FBList {

  private Node front;
  private Person tempPerson;
  private Node tempNode;


  public FBLinkedList() {
    front = null;
  }
  ///////////////
  public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    Node nodeptr = getFront();
    while (nodeptr != null) {
      count++;
      nodeptr = nodeptr.getNext();
    }
    return count;
  }
  //////////////

  public Person lookup(int i){

    if(i<0 || this.size() >0) {
      throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    else if(i<this.size()) {

      Node n = iterator().next();

      for(int index = 0; index < i; index++) {
        n = iterator().next();
      }
      return n.getElement();
    }

  }

  protected Node getFront() {
    return front;
  }


  protected void setFront(Node front) {
    this.front = front;
  }

  public Iterator iterator() {
    return new ListIterator(getFront());
  }

  public static class Node {

    private Person element;


    private Node next;


    public Node(Person element, Node next) {
      this.element = element;
      this.next = next;
    }


    public Person getElement() {
      return element;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
      return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
      this.next = next;
    }
  }



  private static class ListIterator implements Iterator {

    private Node nodeptr;

    public ListIterator(Node first) {
      nodeptr = first;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return (nodeptr != null);
    }

    @Override
    public Node next() {
      try {
        Node element = nodeptr;
        nodeptr = nodeptr.getNext();
        return element;
      } 
      catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Because you're not using generics, everything that *should* be typed is going to return `Object` due to backwards compatibility / legacy support. The code you've written is basically almost 15 years out of date.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception if `this.size() >0` ?

Comment: For this, I do not need the nodes to be generic because I know specifically what I will be putting in them

Comment: You don't seem to understand what generics are for. You're using a rawtype `Iterable` and `ListIterator` which means you have nothing but `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Implement type-safe `Iterable<E>` interface to LinkedList.

```
public class FBLinkedList implements Iterable<Node>...{...}
```

It would change the `Iterator iterator()` generic method to specific `Iterator<Node> iterator()` method.

Comment: Upon doing that, is says that it cannot find Node

Comment: get an idea of LinkedList implementation - [LinkedList java 1.6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java